# Is the injectivity of the operator equivalent to the surjectivity of its adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two normed linear spaces. Let $T:X \to Y^*$ be a linear operator (not necessarily continuous) and let $T^*$ be its adjoint, i.e. $T^*:Y \to X^*$ is defined by

$ \langle T^*y,x \rangle := \langle Tx,y \rangle ,$

where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is a proper duality pairing (i.e. between $X^*$ and $X$ on the left hand side and between $Y^*$ and $Y$ on the right hand side).
Let $R(T)$ denote the range of $T$. Is it true that:

$T$ is injective on $R(T)$ if and only if $T^*$ is surjective onto $X^*$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [$T$ surjective iff $T^*$ injective in infinite-dimensional Hilbert space?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269105/t-surjective-iff-t-injective-in-infinite-dimensional-hilbert-space)

Comment: @NateEldredge This one is about general normed spaces.

Answer (score 4):

The full equivalence does not hold in general. Rather it holds: $T$ is injective if and only if $R(T^*)$ is weak-star dense in $X^*$.

If $T^*$ is surjective, then $T$ is injective: Suppose $Tx=0$, then
$$
0 = \langle Tx,y\rangle_{Y^*,Y} = \langle T^*y,x\rangle_{X^*,X},
$$
and since $R(T^*)=X^*$, it follows $0= \langle x^*,x\rangle_{X^*,X}$ for all $x^*\in X^*$. Hence $x=0$.

Here, it would have been sufficient to suppose that $R(T^*)$ is dense in $X^*$.

Now, let $T$ be injective, assume that $R(T^*)$ is not  weak-star dense in $X^*$. Then there is $x^*\in X^* \setminus \overline{R(T^*)}^{w^*}$, where closure is taken with respect to the weak-star topology. By Hahn-Banach separation theorem, there is $x\in X$, $t\in\mathbb R$, such that 
$$
\langle x^*,x\rangle_{X^*,X} < t \le \langle T^*y,x\rangle_{X^*,X} \quad \forall y\in Y.
$$
Since $T^*$ is linear, it follows $\langle T^*y,x\rangle_{X^*,X}=0$ for all $y\in Y$, which is equivalent to $\langle Tx,y\rangle_{Y^*,Y}=0$ for all $y$. 
Hence $Tx=0$ and by injectivity $x=0$ follows, which is a contradiction.

As a counter-example, which shows that injectivity of $T$ does not implies surjectivity of $T^*$, you can choose any compact and injective $T$, with $X,Y$ being infinite-dimensional. Then $T^*$ is compact as well, but $R(T^*)$ cannot be closed.

Comment: Two comments for this application of Hahn-Banach separation theorem:
1. The theorem states that there exist a $x^{**} \in X^{**}$ s.t. ... Hence you have additionally assumed the reflexivity of $X$.
2. The theorem states that there exists a $t\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. the separation property holds, not necessarily $t=0$.
(see H-B theorem for instance here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_Separation_Theorem)

Comment: 1) H-B works in topological vector spaces as well, so we can really choose $x\in X$. 2) see edit: inserted $t$.

Comment: Thanks for answering my comment.

Comment: Thanks for answering my comment.
1) Unless there is a version of H-B dealing with predual spaces I am not aware of, I don't agree with your explanation. The theorem, considering $X^*$ as a topological vector space, only gives you an element $x^{**}\in X^{**}$ such that $\langle x^{**}, x^* \rangle < t \leq \langle x^{**}, T^* y \rangle $. Representing this $x^{**}$ as some $x\in X$, as stated above, is nothing else but saying that $X$ is reflexive.
2) If we have $t$ instead of $0$ then it is not true that $\langle T^*y,x \rangle =0$ for all $y\in Y$ (take, for instance, $t>0$).

Comment: 1) Talking about topological vector spaces, the dual of $X^*$ ($X^*$ equipped with weak-star topology) is $X$. 2) $y$ is arbitrary from the vector space $Y$. If $\langle T^*y,x\rangle$ would be non-zero for some $y$, then you can take $sy$, $s\in \mathbb R$ to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: @daw: what you say is true, but then your proof shows that the condition is that $R(T^*)$ is weak$^*$-dense, not just norm dense.