# If $T^{*}$ is injective then $T$ is surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

If $T$ is a bounded linear map from the Hilbert space $H_1$ to the Hilbert space $H_2$, and $T^{*}$ is injective, then I know that $H_2$ is the closure of the range of $T$. But can I conclude that $T$ is surjective? Any hint would help. (Sorry if this is trivial.)

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/269105/8157).

Comment: @Guiseppe Sorry I hadn't seen it (I guess this qualifies as a duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $$T:\ell^2\rightarrow\ell^2\\T(x_n;\ n\in\mathbb{N}^+)=\left(\frac{x_n}{n};\ n\in\mathbb{N}^+\right)$$

Notice that $\|T\|\leq1$, but $\left(\frac{1}{n};\ n\in\mathbb{N}^+\right)\notin T(\ell^2)$

But $\forall g\in \ell^{2*}\ (g\circ T=0\rightarrow g=0)$ because $T(\ell^2)$ contains a Hilbert basis.

So the answer to your question is no.